# Windows Vista Window Issue

Tags: windows-vista, multiple-monitors, display

When working on Windows Vista, there seems to be an issue when I plug my laptop into another monitor, using both monitors. The issues is after using both monitors, I unplug my laptop from the other monitor while my laptop is on, but the programs still think there is another monitor not returning to only the laptop screen. Is there a way to auto reposition windows for all programs back to one monitor without doing a reboot? Rebooting is sometimes a big hassle when I am working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to disable the screens of many laptops with an <kbd>Fn</kbd> + other key shortcut.

Comment: This is probably the fastest way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can move a window back onto the visible part of the screen using the window menu.

Right-click the window's icon in the Windows taskbar and you should see a menu appear that looks like this:

[image: Window menu]

Click the `Move` entry and then press an arrow key on your keyboard (doesn't actually matter which one) you should see the mouse pointer change from a cross back to the normal pointer. Just move the mouse pointer back from the edge of the screen and eventually your missing window should appear.

Comment: I have tried this in the past with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a command-line tool called [ResSwitch](http://www.naughter.com/qres.html) that can disable the secondary display, automatically taking all windows back to the primary.  You could copy this

```
resswitch /device:\\.\DISPLAY2 /detach
```

into a batch file and put it on quicklaunch.